# " expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token" and " error: expected ‘)’ before ‘A’"

Tags: c

this is prog in C (adjacency.c) that checks if exists in directed graph way from node a to node b

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

#define N 11
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

typedef  int[N][N] adj_mat;

int path (adj_mat A, int u, int v)





    
void main()
    {
        adj_mat Matrix; 
        int dadnode, sonnode; 

        printf("bla-bla-bla enter nodes.\n");            
             printf("Press Ctrl+Z after finishing  of bla-bla-bla all the nodes\n");
        
        do {    
            printf("Enter the  number of first node\n"); 
            scanf("%d", &dadnode);
            printf("Enter the  number of second node\n");
            scanf("%d", &sonnode;);

            if ((dadnode < sonnode) && (sonnode <= N) && (dadnode > 0)) 
                Matrix[dadnode][sonnode] = 1; 
            } while ( (dadnode != EOF ) && (sonnode != EOF)); 


        printf("Now enter u and v nodes to check if exists way from u node to we node\n")
                        
            printf("Enter the  number of u node\n"); 
            scanf("%d", &dadnode);
            printf("Enter the  number of v node\n");
            scanf("%d", &sonnode;);

            if ((dadnode < sonnode) && (sonnode <= N) && (dadnode > 0)) 
             {
                if(path(Matrix,dadnode,sonnode) == TRUE ) 
                    printf ("Exists way from node u to node v ");   
             }
             
                else printf printf ("Not exists way from node u to node v ");   

    }






int path (adj_mat A, int u, int v) 
    {
        if (v >= u)  
        return FALSE; 

        int nodenum; 

        for(nodenum = v - 1; nodenum > 0; nodenum-- ) 
                                                          
            {
                if (A[nodenum][v] == TRUE) 
                {
                    if (nodenum == u) /
                        return TRUE;

                    else if (path (adj_mat A, int u, int nodenum)) 
                                                
                                
                        return TRUE;
                }
            }   
            
        return FALSE; 
    }
```

when i type command

> gcc -o adjacency -ansi adjacency.c

i get

> adjacency.c:8: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
>
> adjacency.c:10: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘A’
>
> adjacency.c:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘A’

how to fix ?

update:  thanks to all for help. compiled.

Comment: looks like you forgot to add a `;` at the `path()` function decleration on the top of the file.

Comment: `void main()` -- God save you from hell!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should move the `[N][N]` part to the end of the declaration, and add a semicolon after the forward declaration of `path`.

```
typedef  int adj_mat[N][N];
int path (adj_mat A, int u, int v);
```

There are also inaccuracies in the remaining of your code:

- `scanf("%d", &sonnode;);` has extra semicolon, should be `scanf("%d", &sonnode);`
- `else printf printf` should be `else printf`
- Semicolons are missing in a few places
- a `/` is at the end of one line that shouldn't be there
- `main` needs to return an `int`

Answer (score 4):

The type `int[N][N]` is not valid C++.  Try:

```
typedef  int adj_mat[N][N];
```

instead.

Also:

You need a semicolon ('`;`') at the end of lines:

```
int path (adj_mat A, int u, int v) 
printf("Now enter u and v nodes to check if exists way from u node to we node\n")
```

You do not need the first semicolon in

```
scanf("%d", &sonnode;);
```

You have an extra (superfluous) printf in

```
else printf printf ("Not exists way from node u to node v ");
```

You have an invalid line in

```
if (nodenum == u) /
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the semicolon after the function definition on line 10:

```
int path (adj_mat A, int u, int v);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a semicolon missing at the end of below line.

```
int path (adj_mat A, int u, int v);
```